# Rails has many through not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've got 3 models:

**Vacancy**

```
has_many :address_vacancies
has_many :addresses, through: :address_vacancies
```

**Address**

```
has_many :address_vacancies
has_many :vacancies, through: :address_vacancies
```

**AddressVacancy**

```
belongs_to :address
belongs_to :vacancy
```

and in my form I use the following code:

```
<%= f.collection_select :address_id, Address.order("CREATED_AT DESC"),:id,:title, include_blank: true %>
```

which throws an error: `undefined method address_id'`, why is that and what am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

The full form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@vacancy) do |f| %>
  <% if @vacancy.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@vacancy.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this vacancy from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @vacancy.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %>
    <%= f.collection_select :address, Address.order("CREATED_AT DESC"),:id,:title, include_blank: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :signup_until %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :signup_until %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you please run Vacany.attribute_names in the console?

Comment: Can you show more of the form code? Also, can you confirm that your `AddressVacancy` model has an `address_id` column?

Comment: @bratsche yes that model does have that column.

Comment: The code snippet you show (using `:address_id`) doesn't match what you are showing in the full form source (using `:address`). Which one is throwing the error? And neither of them seem correct. Does `@vacancies` have its own `address` attribute? The association will make `@vacancies.addresses` provide a collection of addresses. `@vacancies.address` (and, therefore, `:address`) won't be valid unless `Vacancy` has an `address` attribute. ANd `:address_id` is an attribute of `AddressVacancy` but not of `Vacancy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :address %>
  <%= f.collection_select :address, Address.order("CREATED_AT DESC"),:id,:title, include_blank: true %>
</div>
```

Isn't valid in the context of a `Vacancy` form (from the `form_for @vacancy`) since a `Vacancy` doesn't have a single address attribute. It has a collection of addresses through the `has_many` association. It would also be invalid to use `:address_id` for the same reason.

If you want to edit the various addresses for the one vacancy, you would need a subform. You'd use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the model, and `fields_for` in the view.

```
<%= form_for @vacancy do |f| %>
  ...

  <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |af| %>
    ...
    <!-- Here you'd render a partial or a set of inputs for this address %>
    <%= af.input :street %> <!-- e.g., if there's a street attribute for Address -->
    ...
  <% end %>

  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: So I cannot use has many through like a regular select field?

Comment: @Xeen, the `addresses` association is not a field in the `Vacancy`. It represents a collection of records from another table that are associated with the current record in the `Vacancy` table. The `Vacancy` record doesn't have one attribute that represents a choice selected from the association (unless you explicitly create such an attribute in the `Vacancy` table). `has many` means a `Vacancy` *has many* addresses, not just one that is set with a selector.